About Hom (TM ,Hom (TM,ν))≅ Hom (TM⊗TM,ν)
In the book ," Characteristic Classes "  by J.W.Milnor and J.D.Stasheff there is a problem ( 5-B) in which the following isomorphism had been mentioned:
Hom ($TM$ ,Hom ($TM ,\nu )) \cong $ Hom $(TM \otimes TM , \nu )$ where $TM$ is tangent bundle and $\nu$ is normal bundle i.e $ (TM)^\bot $ .
How can I show this isomorphism ?
As I thought , is the following :
Suppose $E$ and $F$ be two  $n$-plane bundle over a base space $B$ and $\pi_1: E \rightarrow B $  and $ \pi_2: E \rightarrow B$  be the projection maps . So Hom$(E,F)=  \amalg_{b\in B}$ Hom $(E_b , F_b )$ where  $E_b:=\pi_1^-1(b) , F_b :=\pi_2^-1(b)$. So here each $TM_x$ for all $x \in M$
is n-dim vector space as $M$ is n-dim manifold and if we assume $M$ is embedded in $R^{n
+k}$ then $\nu_x$ is $k$-dim vector space . So Hom$(TM_x,\nu_x)$ is $nk$-dim vector space and Hom$(TM_x , $ Hom $(TM_x,\nu_x)_x) $ is $n^2k$-dim vcetor space. Also $TM_x \otimes TM_x$ is $n^2$-dim and Hom $( TM_x \otimes TM_x , \nu_x)$ is $n^2k$-dim vector spaces . So as vector space ,Hom ($TM$ ,Hom ($TM_x ,\nu_x )) \cong $ Hom $(TM_x \otimes TM_x , \nu_x ) $ and this implies Hom ($TM$ ,Hom ($TM ,\nu )) \cong $ Hom $(TM \otimes TM , \nu )$ .
Am I right ?

Observe that your proof would show that all vector bundles of the same rank are isomorphic: after all their fibres are by definition isomorphic at each point. But this is obviously false, so no, this does not work.

You need to understand thoroughly how the multilinear algebra isomorphism $\text{Hom}(V,\text{Hom}(V,W)) \cong \text{Hom}(V\otimes V,W)$ is natural.

@BenSteffan yes . I am wrong . I have to give a continuous map from the total space to total space which carries fibers isomorphically .
